# Removing specific deadkey assignment on international keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

It took me a couple of tries until I managed to get dead keys to work on my machine. Thanks to some questions here in this forum I got it.

My main usecases are to write in English, Portuguese and sometimes use some Danish characters like `ø`. I noticed though that there are plenty of deadkey combinations that I don't need and only cause trouble.

For example:
to type `he's` or `she's` I usually get `heś` and `sheś`, respectively

Or to type `don't` I actually get the error blip and the word `don`.

So the question is: does anyone know how to customize particular combinations of keys?

I would love to map
`'t` to `'t` (itself, instead of an error) and

`'+s` to `'s` instead of  `ś`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I do not have the answer on your specific question, but I have a suggestion to go another way around the problem. Install two keyboard layouts, the English (US, intl., with dead keys) that you appear to be using now, and the default English (US) keyboard. Set the latter one as your default. Then, for the times you need the foreign characters, switch to the other keyboard layout using a hotkey, <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> by default in a default Ubuntu installation with the Gnome desktop.

In standard Ubuntu, You can add keyboard layouts in "Settings" - "Region & Language", under "Input sources"

It may be easier to change habits when working with the international layout. I notice that I automatically hit <kbd>'</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> when wanting to type a "'".

You can effectively edit keyboard layouts, but that becomes technical. Here you can find [an explanation of how keyboard layouts are defined](http://people.uleth.ca/%7Edaniel.odonnell/Blog/custom-keyboard-in-linuxx11).